# Quick Smooth Resizing of Bitmaps

Tags: delphi, bitmap

I am trying to write my own quick resampler which allows to scale image down by 2,3,4 etc.
I compared it with StretchBlt and my resampler is about 2 times slower.

My code:

```
 type TRGBA = record
   B,G,R: Byte;
   A: Byte;
 end;

 PRGBAArray = ^TRGBAArray;
 TRGBAArray = array[0..32767] of TRGBA;

procedure DownsampleSys(Src, Dst: TBitmap; Times: Integer);
var ARect: TRect;
    dc:HDC;
    p:TPoint;
begin
  Dst.Width := Src.Width div Times;
  Dst.Height := Src.Height div Times;

  ARect := Rect(0,0, Dst.Width, Dst.Height);

  dc := Dst.Canvas.Handle;
  GetBrushOrgEx(dc,p);
  SetStretchBltMode(dc,HALFTONE);
  SetBrushOrgEx(dc,p.x,p.y,@p);
  StretchBlt(dc,
    ARect.Left, ARect.Top,
    ARect.Right- ARect.Left, ARect.Bottom- ARect.Top,
    Src.Canvas.Handle,0,0,Src.Width,Src.Height,Dst.Canvas.CopyMode);
end;

procedure Downsample2(Src, Dst: TBitmap; Times: Integer);
var x,y: Integer;
    xx,yy: Integer;
    FromP, ToP: PRGBAArray;
    SumR, SumG, SumB: Cardinal;
    Times2: Integer;
    xTimes, yTimes: Integer;
    xxxTimes: Integer;
    MarginL, MarginT: Integer;
begin
  Dst.Width := floor(Src.Width/ Times);
  Dst.Height := floor(Src.Height / Times);
  Times2 := Times * Times;
  MarginL := (Src.Width - (Dst.Width * Times)) div 2;
  MarginT := (Src.Height - (Dst.Height * Times)) div 2;

  for y:=0 to Dst.Height-1 do begin
    ToP := Dst.Scanline[y];

    yTimes := MarginT + y*Times;

    for x:=0 to Dst.Width-1 do begin

      SumR := 0;
      SumG := 0;
      SumB := 0;

      xTimes := MarginL + x*Times;

      for yy:=0 to Times-1 do begin
        FromP := Src.Scanline[yy + yTimes];

        for xx:=0 to Times-1 do begin
          xxxTimes := xx + xTimes;
          SumR := SumR + FromP[xxxTimes].R;
          SumG := SumG + FromP[xxxTimes].G;
          SumB := SumB + FromP[xxxTimes].B;
        end;
      end;

      ToP[x].R := SumR div Times2;
      ToP[x].G := SumG div Times2;
      ToP[x].B := SumB div Times2;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Usage:

```
InB := TBitmap.Create;
OutB := TBitmap.Create;

InB.LoadFromFile('2.bmp');
InB.PixelFormat := pf32bit;

OutB.PixelFormat := pf32bit;

Downsample2(InB, OutB, 4);
```

How can I make it even faster?

Comment: If the RGB values are bytes then you can sum into words instead of cardinals until scaling down by a factor of more than 256. Likely not a major increase however.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still interested in an answer, you could give this thumbnail-routine a try. It's the result of a discussion way back on the Borland newsgroups. On my system it runs a bit faster than Stretch_Halftone, but the box-rescaling is a bit too foggy for my taste. I've abandoned all box-rescaling myself, because the system-rescaling, on my graphics at least, looks better; almost as if it was using bicubic scaling behind the scenes.

The speed gain is by use of lookup-tables, pointer- and integer-math.

```
// procedure MakeThumbnailMod
// Original source: Roy Magne Klever
// Altered to avoid division by 0
// and tried to make it a bit faster (RS)
//Integer math courtesy of Hagen Redmann

type
  PRGB32 = ^TRGB32;

  TRGB32 = packed record
    b: byte;
    g: byte;
    r: byte;
    a: byte;
  end;

  TLine32 = array [0 .. maxint div SizeOf(TRGB32) - 1] of TRGB32;
  PLine32 = ^TLine32;

  TIntArray = array of integer;
  TDeltaArray = array of array of integer;

procedure MakeStepsAndWeights(xscale, yscale: Single; xw, yh: integer;
  var dxmin, dymin: integer; var Weights: TDeltaArray;
  var xsteps, ysteps: TIntArray);
var
  i, j: integer;
  x1, x2: integer;
  dxmax, dymax, intscale: integer;
  fact: Single;
begin
  SetLength(xsteps, xw);
  SetLength(ysteps, yh);
  intscale := round(xscale * $10000);
  // won't work if xcale > $10000/2, because then intscale
  // exceeds 32bit integer. I don't see that happening.
  x1 := 0;
  x2 := intscale shr 16;
  for i := 0 to xw - 1 do
  begin
    xsteps[i] := x2 - x1;
    x1 := x2;
    x2 := (i + 2) * intscale shr 16;
  end;
  dxmin := Ceil(xscale - 1);
  dxmax := trunc(xscale + 1);

  intscale := round(yscale * $10000);
  x1 := 0;
  x2 := intscale shr 16;
  for i := 0 to yh - 1 do
  begin
    ysteps[i] := x2 - x1;
    x1 := x2;
    x2 := (i + 2) * intscale shr 16;
  end;
  dymin := Ceil(yscale - 1);
  dymax := trunc(yscale + 1);
  SetLength(weights, dxmax - dxmin + 1, dymax - dymin + 1);
  for i := 0 to dxmax - dxmin do
  begin
    fact := 1 / (dxmin + i);
    for j := 0 to dymax - dymin do
      weights[i, j] := round(fact / (dymin + j) * $10000);
  end;
end;

procedure MakeThumbNailMod(const Src, Dest: TBitmap;
  NewWidth, NewHeight: integer);
var
  xscale, yscale: Single;
  x1: integer;
  ix, iy: integer;
  totalRed, totalGreen, totalBlue: integer;
  ratio: integer;
  p: PRGB32;
  pt1: PRGB32;
  ptrD, ptrS: integer;
  x, y: integer;
  r1, r2: TRect;
  x3: integer;
  RowDest, RowSource, RowSourceStart: integer;
  weights: TDeltaArray;
  xsteps, ysteps: TIntArray;
  w, h, dxmin, dymin: integer;
  dx, dy: integer;

begin
  Dest.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  Src.PixelFormat:=pf32bit; //to be on the safe side
  Dest.Width := NewWidth;
  Dest.Height := NewHeight;
  if (Dest.Width >= Src.Width) or (Dest.Height >= Src.Height) then
  begin  //we don't do upsampling
    r1 := rect(0, 0, Src.Width, Src.Height);
    r2 := r1;
    OffsetRect(r2, (Dest.Width - Src.Width) div 2,
      (Dest.Height - Src.Height) div 2);
    Dest.Canvas.CopyRect(r2, Src.Canvas, r1);
    exit;
  end;
  w := Dest.Width;
  h := Dest.Height;
  ptrD := (w * 32 + 31) and not 31;
  ptrD := ptrD div 8; // BytesPerScanline
  ptrS := (Src.Width * 32 + 31) and not 31;
  ptrS := ptrS div 8;

  xscale := Src.Width / w;
  yscale := Src.Height / h; // turns div into mults
  MakeStepsAndWeights(xscale, yscale, w, h, dxmin, dymin, weights, xsteps, ysteps);
  // Make 3 lookup tables for the steps and the ratios

  w := w - 1;
  h := h - 1;
  RowDest := integer(Dest.Scanline[0]);
  RowSourceStart := integer(Src.Scanline[0]);
  RowSource := RowSourceStart;
  for y := 0 to h do
  begin
    dy := ysteps[y];
    x1 := 0;
    x3 := 0;
    for x := 0 to w do
    begin
      dx := xsteps[x];
      totalRed := 0;
      totalGreen := 0;
      totalBlue := 0;
      RowSource := RowSourceStart;
      for iy := 1 to dy do
      begin
        p := PRGB32(RowSource + x1);
        for ix := 1 to dx do
        begin
          totalRed := totalRed + p^.r;
          totalGreen := totalGreen + p^.g;
          totalBlue := totalBlue + p^.b; //maybe add the alpha-channel optionally
          inc(p);
        end;
        RowSource := RowSource - ptrS;
      end;
      pt1 := PRGB32(RowDest + x3);
      ratio := weights[dx - dxmin, dy - dymin];
      pt1^.r := (totalRed * ratio) shr 16;  //"rounding"
      pt1^.g := (totalGreen * ratio) shr 16;
      pt1^.b := (totalBlue * ratio) shr 16;
      x1 := x1 + 4 * dx;
      x3 := x3 + 4;
    end;
    RowDest := RowDest - ptrD;
    RowSourceStart := RowSource;
  end;
  //SharpenMod(Work, Dest, min(1 + 0.4 * (xscale - 1), 2.5));
  //The sharpening makes the thumb look nicer, but is omitted here
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it. I read that StretchBlt is hardware accelerated on modern systems so it might be hard to beat it.

Comment: Thank you, Renate! Wine for Linux and Mac doesn't seem to honor the stretchblt halftoning, so I was looking for some custom code and this works great. I just need to add a little sharpening as you mentioned. Thanks again!